# Why is my DBI connector doing a dummy query with predicate "where 0 = 1"?

Tags: r, dbi, monetdb, dbplyr

I have some R test code that I use to connect to a MonetDB instance.

I notice that for each connection that I create through `tbl(conn, "some_table")` I somehow always end up with a 'primer' query of the 
form

```
SELECT *
FROM "some_table" AS "zzz1"
WHERE (0 = 1)
```

So if I run the code

```
conn <- dbConnect(MonetDB.R(), host="localhost", dbname="testdb", user="monetdb", password="monetdb")
foo <- tbl(conn, "foo")
foo %>% filter(bar %like%  '%baz%') %>% collect()
```

I end up with two queries in the output

```
QQ: 'SELECT *
FROM "foo" AS "zzz1"
WHERE (0 = 1)'
QQ: Query result for query 0 with 0 rows and 34 cols, 0 rows.
QQ: 'SELECT *
FROM "foo")
WHERE ("bar" LIKE '%baz%')'
QQ: Query result for query 1 with 20 rows and 2 cols, 20 rows.
```

I do not understand where this additional query comes from. As far as I know DBI should not perform any dummy query by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr` auto-generates and runs this query to get the columns for the table. This is needed to figure out whether `bar` in `filter` exists in the table for example.

Comment: Ok, I guessed something like that. Problem is that MonetDB does not recognize that 
`WHERE 0 = 1` or even `WHERE FALSE`  is an anti-tautology in its MAL plan generation. I think this warrants a  new MAL optimizer that checks for and shortcuts these anti-tautologies.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Does it take long to process?

Comment: Yup on a big table it does a full scan. I made a MonetDB bug report for it:
https://www.monetdb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6677

Comment: Indeed then this could/should be detected. DuckDB does. I also suspect that the sequential pipeline will not have the same problem in MonetDB.

Comment: It actually does: check the reproduction steps in the bug report.